# sapui5 access to controller without id

Tags: sapui5

i'm new at sapui5. I have a List where each element contains a Button and an Image. I want to change the image src by pressing button (only imagewhich is part of list element same as button). Is it possible to get access to image withou id? (How to do it?)

Xml code:

```
<List items="{data>/Stages}">
   <CustomListItem>
      <Panel>
         <headerToolbar>
            <Toolbar class="topDetailToolbar" style="Clear">
               <Title class="sapUiSmallMarginBegin fieldWorkTitle" text="{data>Name}" titleStyle="H2" />
               <ToolbarSpacer />
               <Button text="{i18n>TECH_CARD_ROLL}" class="addButton sapUiSmallMarginBottom" press="onVisibleFilters" />
               <core:Icon src="sap-icon://navigation-up-arrow" size="1rem" color="#00c0db" visible="{confFilter>/filterUp}" />
            </Toolbar>
         </headerToolbar>
      </Panel>
   </CustomListItem>
</List>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by adding the style `class` to icon and get the instance of the icon using `jQuery` and reset using `setSrc()`

**Event handler** - `onVisibleFilters` to change the icon `src`

```
onVisibleFilters: function(oEvent) {
  var oToolbarId = oEvent.getSource().getParent().sId;//get Parent toolbar of button
  var sIconId = jQuery("#" + oToolbarId).find(".hdrIcon").attr("id");//get Icon id using jQuery and hdrIcon class
  if(sIconId) {
      var oIcon = sap.ui.getCore().byId(sIconId);
      if(oIcon) oIcon.setSrc("sap-icon://lab");//update the icon src  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you should do:

```js
var oButton = oEvent.getSource(); //this returns the button which triggers the press event
var oListItem = oButton.getParent(); //returns the listItem in which the button was pressed

var aCells = oListItem.getAggregation("cells");
```

you should be able to find the image in one of the indexes in the cells array.

Comment: But how can i figure out what the current cell index by button press?
And could you pls give me an example: let's say the cell index is 0 so how can i get a Image& (or another elements in this cell)

Comment: You do not need the index of the row. You need the index of the cell where the image is bound. 

var oImageUrl = aCells[0]   //here 0th cell in the table columns is the imageURL. Let me know if this helps.